# Deleting old logs in elasticsearch came from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-curator

I wanted to delete the old logs in elastic search which came from the logstash.

I have read regarding the curator which can be used for removing this.

But it always points that it will remove old indices which is older than so many days. Will it actually remove my indices if I execute it ? or just old logs in that particular index.

I have custom index like a, b , c etc. I dont have timestring parameters in my indices.

curator delete indices --older-than 14 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d --regex '^logstash-'

How to execute the deletion of indices in these format.?

Comment: Curator is deleting entire indices, based on their name pattern (which should include a date). So, the index name should include a date pattern in it and Curator will use that to establish if your command covers that index or not.

Answer (score 0):

Curator cannot remove data from an index.  It can only remove one or more indices.  This makes it especially hard for you since your index hames are not time-series in nature (the a, b, c, etc. you mentioned).

You should switch to using time-series indices and gradually phase out the named, non-timeseries indices.

It's also apparent you're reading about older versions of curator, based on the syntax you're sharing.  That is the old Curator 3.x syntax.  Curator 3.x is deprecated, as it only supports Elasticsearch 1.x indices and 2.x indices.  Curator 4.x supports 2.x indices, and 5.x indices.  Curator 5.x support Elasticsearch 5.x indices only. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.3/version-compatibility.html

Comment: Then how to purge old logs from an index? Currently for 1.7G of actual log data elastic search has created almost 15G of log.. and i need to cleanup some old log which is older than say 20days..

Comment: You will need to investigate how to use delete_by_query.  This is exceptionally sub-optimal for time-series use cases.